# Subir imagen a un BlobStorage de Azure

Tags: c#, azure

Estoy tratando de subir imágenes a un blobstorage de azure desde mi aplicación. Leyendo la documentación y aplicando su método consigo esto al visualizar la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi método es el siguiente (_filename es el path de la imagen en mi pc):

```
private async Task<string> CargarImagenPerfilAzure(string username)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_filename))
            {
                Uri blobUri = new Uri($"urlasociadaalblobstoragequenohacefaltaespecificar{Path.GetExtension(_filename)}");
                StorageSharedKeyCredential storageCredentials = new StorageSharedKeyCredential("key", "password");
                BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(blobUri, storageCredentials);

                FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(Path.GetFullPath(_filename));
                await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, true);
                fileStream.Close();

                if (await Task.FromResult(true))
                {
                    return blobUri.ToString();
                }
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
```

No entiendo por qué me está pasando esto. ¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Creo que hace falta un slash después de `urlasociadaalblobstoragequenohacefaltaespecificar` Saludos.

Comment: No, la url esta bien al 100%. Me crea un contenedor y sube una imagen al contenedor de Azure pero cuando abres la imagen sale lo de la foto que hay en la pregunta. Es a lo que me quiero referir, no debe cargar bien la imagen. Crea un archivo .jpg| .png o lo que sea pero no muestra la información en ello.